# Java jbutton in another class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a button in a class which removes something from a table. I have it working when it's not in a separate class. However, when I try and move the code to a new class and create an object of that class in my main method, the button doesn't work. I'm pretty new to using Swing, so any help will be much appreciated.

```
public abstract class RemoveButton extends frame implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
      if (table.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
        if (table.getRowCount() == 0) {
          Mess.setText("Table is empty");
        } else {
          Mess.setText("You need to select");
        }
      } else {
        model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This class is the button which is supposed to remove a guest. I extended the frame, because that is where most of my variables are. From here, I am not so sure as of how to call this to my main method and get it working. All the imports have been added.

Comment: "the button doesn't work." What does this mean? Is there an exception thrown? Where's the stack trace?

Comment: it doesn't remove the guest in the table, no exception is throw, the button simply doesn't work when I put that code in a different class.

Comment: I suspect that you're using inheritance for the wrong purposes. Why does this class extend frame? Is it to access frame's fields and methods? If so, this is not what you should be doing. Instead you need to pass a frame reference into the class and call its methods. Also, why is the class abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess here, which we're forced to do since the question as written presently is incomplete, but I suspect that you're misusing inheritance. I'm guessing that your main GUI is held by the frame class (which should be re-named to comply with Java standards so that it's first letter is upper case), and are doing this so that this class can call methods and access fields of the frame class. If so, then you're using inheritance for the wrong purpose since the "frame" instance held by RemoveButton is unique and completely different from the frame instance that is displayed.

Instead, you should pass into this class a reference to the actual displayed frame object, and then call methods on this object as needed.

e.g.,

```
// why abstract? I've removed that
// no longer extends frame
public class RemoveButton implements ActionListener {
   // I've renamed your frame class to "MyFrame"
   private MyFrame myFrame;

   // constructor that allows you to pass in MyFrame reference
   public RemoveButton(MyFrame myFrame) {
      this.myFrame = myFrame;  // assign to field
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      JTable table = myFrame.getTable(); // give MyFrame this method
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
      // .... etc
   }      
}
```

Cleaner would be to use a MVC design pattern, but that would require some more up-front work.